# Как "закрепить" программу на рабочем столе?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7

Есть программа часы. Как ее сделать "закрепленной" на рабочем столе, т.е., что бы при переходе на него отображались часы. Не знаю с какой стороны браться за это.
Что то типа виджета для Windows 7.

Comment: Что такое программа закрепленная на рабочем столе? Вы имеете ввиду виджет, по типу виджета погоды в стандартной поставке Windows? И кстати, уточните плиз целевую версию Windows.

Comment: Да, типа виджет. Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Простой пример создания гаджета без программирования (сам по себе гаджет - это html-страничка):

Создайте два файла:

gadget.xml — манифест гаджета

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gadget>
  <name>Hello World!</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <hosts>
    <host name="sidebar">
    <base type="HTML" apiVersion="1.0.0" src="gadget.html" />
    <permissions>full</permissions>
    <platform minPlatformVersion="0.3" />
    </host>
  </hosts>
</gadget>
```

gadget.html — основной файл гаджета

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 130px;
        height: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Запакуйте их в zip архив с расширением gadget.

Это и есть дистрибутив гаджета. Устанавливайте.
Более подробно написано [здесь](http://designformasters.info/posts/windows-sidebar-gadget/).

Если нужно именно на delphi, то посмотрите на эту [статью](http://www.delphisources.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=13491).